# "Insufficient information" reason does not seem to be correct

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Consider the question [Randomly generate a fixed size array of integers with a given total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760391/randomly-generate-a-fixed-size-array-of-integers-with-a-given-total).

Three reviewers voted to close it because

> This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

and two voted to close it because

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

The second reason seems totally off-base.

But I want to focus on the first reason.. The question seems clear.

> Given a value `$z`, it should get distributed in given number of days in a month randomly, and when we total all the random distributed numbers, the result should be equal to the given value $z.

He also includes a (partial) example.

*The OP wants to generate `n` random numbers that sum to `z`.*

I have absolutely no question about what the OP want to do.

Granted, he seems to be a help vampire, and the question was downvoted forty-three times, **but did he really not include enough information?**

---

This seems to be a growing trend on SO, where poor quality or help vampire questions are closed because they "lack sufficient information**.

It just seems wrong. Is it?

Comment: Woah, how did that get down to -43? Almost nothing gets that low before it is deleted.

Comment: @Mysticial, seriously. I've never seen a vote that low before.

Comment: I've seen lower. But they all got linked from somewhere (like Reddit or HN). This question only has 200 views.

Comment: There's gems [like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012373/recursion-adding-numbers) [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029651/fastest-way-in-c-sharp-to-iterate-through-all-guids-possible). But both have high view counts from Reddit and such.

Comment: My impression of the use of this reason seems to have, at it's core, the assumption that there is actually an attempted solution, it's just not shown, and since it's not shown, we can't explain what's wrong with it or how to fix it.  Now, I'm not saying that I *agree* with that line of thought, but that seems to be what it is.

Comment: sometimes there is just no valid off-topic reason to click. the 'off topic -> other' reason is only available if the user has a certain amount of rep (which i dont have), so there are some questions that I know are wrong but which I don't flag because there is no proper flag reason for it. other users may decide to put an invalid flag on the question instead of putting no flag at all on a bad question.

Comment: "No valid off-topic reason" -> May not be off topic.  Be careful about that; dealing with low-quality questions, the best way is to either vote for closure (for the specific closure reasons provided), downvote, or both.

Comment: @Makoto ok, I will post a question on meta-SO the next time I encounter such a question...

Comment: @Servy, this does seem to be what it is, though this thought does not actually match the words.

Answer (score 3):

Trawling through [the revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23760391/revisions) of the post doesn't inspire much confidence in the attempt to actually get an answer from the community...around the second edit, the user appeared to have "given up the ghost" and modified their question into spam.

However, **they come back** to add **more detail** to their question (after the spam was removed).  Not just that, but an answer there is actually pretty good (at least 19 upvotes).

Admittedly, the close reason vote came *before* the question was updated, so in theory the system works; however, it somehow became a magnet for downvotes, leading to its deletion.

A vampire help question should be downvoted such that it no longer appears in any relevant search.  But, while this one looked like a question from a help vampire, it no longer appears to be the case (at least, from my perspective).

It'd take a miracle to see those downvotes overturned, but I don't have any qualms with that question anymore.  I'd vote to <s>reopen</s> undelete it.